# Unable to filter dataframe by dates in R

Tags: r

I am trying to filter my dataset by date. Given that my current dates are in character format, I am trying to convert them to a date format.
Here is what I tried to do:

```
total$Date <- as.Date(total$Date)
```

But I get an error message that says:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Here is a sample of my Date column:

```
> dput(total$Date)
c("2/26/2020", "4/17/2020", "6/9/2022", "2/17/2022", "8/30/2020", 
"1/16/2021", "5/4/2021", "11/25/2021", "2/4/2020", "8/12/2022", 
"11/4/2019", "1/28/2022", "2/19/2022", "7/1/2020", "9/15/2021", 
"12/24/2021", "10/14/2021", "9/1/2022", "2/28/2022", "5/4/2020", 
"5/18/2022", "12/7/2021", "1/17/2020", "2/2/2022", "10/22/2020", 
"9/18/2021", "12/7/2021", "11/11/2019", "4/3/2020", "7/28/2021", 
"1/16/2021", "1/12/2022", "8/25/2020", "6/3/2022", "3/3/2021", 
"12/19/2019", "7/14/2021", "5/14/2022", "5/15/2022", "12/10/2020", 
"5/11/2022", "7/11/2020", "1/11/2020", "8/3/2022", "3/24/2021", 
"10/11/2019", "7/16/2022", "8/26/2020", "4/13/2022", "12/1/2021", 
"1/9/2021", "2/15/2020", "4/23/2021", "2/5/2021", "5/10/2022", 
"6/9/2021", "7/14/2020", "3/19/2021", "8/8/2022", "6/29/2022", 
"1/8/2022", "7/26/2020", "10/14/2021", "2/6/2022", "3/2/2022", 
"3/11/2021", "2/7/2022", "10/3/2021", "12/12/2020", "12/8/2020", 
"5/15/2022", "1/5/2021", "7/16/2021", "10/9/2019", "4/15/2020", 
"6/20/2022", "3/13/2020", "4/15/2022", "9/25/2019", "6/28/2022", 
"11/4/2019", "4/10/2020", "9/26/2020", "9/29/2020", "8/29/2022", 
"6/12/2020", "11/15/2020", "2/3/2022", "12/7/2020", "8/28/2020", 
"9/29/2020", "7/18/2022", "6/24/2020", "7/30/2020", "8/31/2020", 
"8/1/2021", "10/8/2019", "8/3/2021", "9/10/2021", "9/11/2020"
)
```

I am trying to filter the data frame by date so that rows between the dates of `6/1/2022` and `8/9/2022` are included.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you what the problem is:

> character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

In some locales, dates are usually written in the `DD/MM/YYYY` format, and in others in `MM/DD/YYYY`. From the fact that your dataset contains dates like "2/26/2020", it looks like you are using the latter. You have to tell `as.Date` this fact so that it knows which number is the month and which is the day.

```
total$Date <- as.Date(total$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

head(total$Date)
[1] "2020-02-26" "2020-04-17" "2022-06-09" "2022-02-17" "2020-08-30" "2021-01-16"
```

As you see, R avoids the ambiguity by printing the dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. If you want to print your dates in the US format, you can use the `format` function:

```
head(format(total$Date, '%m/%d/%Y'))
[1] "02/26/2020" "04/17/2020" "06/09/2022" "02/17/2022" "08/30/2020" "01/16/2021"
```

Comment: Thank you. I made the change, but when I filter it I still get this error message: > total[(total$Date> "2022-06-01" & total$Date < "2022-08-09"),]
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Comment: That looks like a separate problem and it may be better to ask a new question.